# Python - Class Content manager. Why __exit__ method is omitted if you put yield inside of it?

Tags: python, yield, contextmanager

```
class OracleConnected():
    def __init__(self):
        self.oracle_username = oracle_username[1]
        self.oracle_password = oracle_password[1]
        self.dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(hostname[1], port[1], sid[1])
    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            print('Then this')
            cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=lib_dir)
            self.connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user=self.oracle_username, password=self.oracle_password, dsn=self.dsn)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error connecting to Oracle: \n{e}')
        else:
            yield self.connection

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
            print('Finally do this')
            #self.connection.close()
            yield self.connection.close()


with OracleConnected() as connection:
    print('It first do this')
    cur = next(connection).cursor()
    cur.execute("select *From payments where id = 324986093")
    print(cur.fetchall())
```

1. If everything stays the same I got:
   It first do this
   Then this
   [(324986093, 391908893, 391908893, 1228, None, datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 24, 0, 0)]
2. Instead of yield self.connection.close() -> write just self.connection.close():
   It first do this
   Then this
   [(324986093, 391908893, 391908893, 1228, None, datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 24, 0, 0)]
   Finally do this

**So the question is, what is so special about yield that it gives me so much troubles?**

P.S. Also, Instead of yield self.connection.close() -> return self.connection.close()
I got desired answer:
It first do this
Then this
[(324986093, 391908893, 391908893, 1228, None, datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 24, 0, 0)]
Finally do this

P.S.S. On top of that, If I may ask - imagine that we solve this mystery. Another problem in the same code, if i get an error while connecting to server using self.connection and say it gives an error then i passed this error to **exit** and exit gives me an error as well - how to handle this situation also. So i did not pass it to **exit**?

I tried to read documentations, but nothing seemed to work. I just curious what are the causes of omitting **exit**

Comment: Why are you trying to use `yield` instead of `return`?  Do you understand that by having a `yield` statement inside a function, it turns that function into a generator?  `yield` and `return` are very different.

Comment: Ineed there is no need to prefer `yield` over return 

Nonetheless, I just wanted to try it out, and it gives me this weird result 

And so the question remains, why yield gives one result, and return gives another 

Why when I use yield it skips entireliy __exit__ method as If it does not exist. On the other hand, when I change yield -> return (and do some changes inside with so it can work with function instead of generator) it "goes" inside __exit__ close connection and does print('Finally do this')

Comment: `yield` doesn't exactly skip the `__exit__` method.  It just behaves differently.  When called, rather than immediately executing the function body, is instead returns a generator.  If you later call `next` on the returned generator (either directly or by iterating over it), *then* the function body will be executed, up until it executes the `yield` statement.  *Read about `yield` and generators.*  That would make far more sense than trying them at random, then trying to elicit a redundant, personalized explanation from someone as you've done.

Comment: The thing you need to understand is that if a function contains a `yield` statement anywhere in the function body, then calling it behaves differently, right from the start, before any statements in the function have been executed.  Instead, calling it returns a generator.  Execution of the function body doesn't actually begin until `next` (or the equivalent) is applied to the returned generator.

Comment: You are absolutely right I shoud have read more carefully about `yield` first, I just got stuck and did not know what to do or what is the reason why It does not work. Thank you very much

Comment: If you want to learn about generators, you should put this aside and instead just write a very simple generator that you can experiment with. without classes or the oracle stuff.  Just write a simple generator, then call it and save the result, then repeatedly call `next` on it and watch what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__enter__` and `__exit__` shouldn't have `yield` because then they'll return a generator and you have to iterate over the generator to completion for the method to finish executing.

You may be getting confused with [`@contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) which is a decorator that can be applied to a generator function to create a simple context manager without having to write a class with `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

Comment: I might have got confused.

But would you might explaining why in my case using `yield` is a bad idea? Inside `with` body i do some work such as `next(connection)` to work with a generator that  class `OracleConnected()` provides.

And when I do instead of `yield` -> `return` and also do some changes inside with statement it will work perfectly fine and gose inside `__exit__`?

Comment: In your code, using yield automatically means that the methods returns generators. `__enter__` returns a generator, so `connection` in `with OracleConnected() as connection:` is a generator. `next(connection)` advances the generator and returns `self.connection` from `yield self.connection`. But `__exit__` also returns a generator and there's nothing calling `next()` or anything on that returned generator, so the code inside doesn't run at all because it's waiting. Just like if you remove the `next()` it'll never run the code in `__enter__` including `print('Then this')`.

Comment: Yes, okay now it makes sense. Thank you very much!